# How to prevent Qt Applications from using GTK+ theme

Tags: gtk, theme, qt, qtcreator

Whenever I want to use custom QML components in my apps it makes them use GTK+ theme. How can I prevent this?

Why am I asking here? Because I believe it has something to do with files like: `~/.config/qt.conf` or whatever. And I have to do something like:

```
[Qt]
GTK-theme: false
```

Or something in this "style", but I don't know what/how exactly should I do it. Can you help me with this?

**I'm using ArchLinux and GNOME as DE if it can help.**